# Multistore, template code from code/local/

Tags: magento

I'm prepare a multistore on magento.
I have a three template, and I was change a few file from code/core and replace in code/local, but only one template take a changing code from code/local
a rest template should take file from code/core/
Now every template take files from code/local/
How can I'm set app to resolve a problem
thx for help

Answer (score 3):

You should NOT overwrite core files in local. Better try to develop your own module which rewrites the core functionality. In this module you can integrate a configuration, so it's only used for one store view, and not for all.

Comment: I created a own module and overriding a block eg. Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu, I would like using this overriding  block only in one theme, but if i change the theme the magento take a overriding block, how set magento to realize this problem